# C++ Metaprogramming to check type existence

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

The source code below is excerpted from MongoDB.

I understand that `detect_clone_factory_type_member_impl` serves the purpose of checking whether the type `T` possesses a `clone_factory_type` or not. However, what puzzles me is that since `Derived` inherits from both `T` and `Fallback`, regardless of whether `T` has a `clone_factory_type`, `Derived` should always possess a `clone_factory_type`. Wouldn't that mean the first test function, `No& test(typename U::clone_factory_type*)`, should always be chosen?

When I actually run experiments, this routine works as expected, which makes me very curious as to how this mechanism functions. I would appreciate the expertise of various professionals.

```
template <typename T>
struct detect_clone_factory_type_member_impl {
    struct Fallback {
        struct clone_factory_type {};
    };

    struct Derived : T, Fallback {};

    using Yes = char[2];
    using No = char[1];

    template <typename U>
    static No& test(typename U::clone_factory_type*);

    template <typename U>
    static Yes& test(U*);

    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<Derived>(nullptr)) == sizeof(Yes);

    using type = typename std::integral_constant<bool, value>::type;
};
```

Comment: This is a very old style way (C++11) of implementing SFINAE.  [cppreference : SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Is there another modern way for this?

Comment: Yes concepts (C++20). For example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761720/ensure-class-methods-with-c20-concepts